# Как исправить ош

Tags: c++, c

```
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int SIZE = 9;
    int hon[SIZE];


    for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++) {

        hon[i] = rand() % 10;
        cout << hon[i] << endl;

}

return 0;

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как исправить ошибку?Перезапускаю студию создаю новие проекти тоже самое.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                  ^
```

Comment: А поему изза = оно не работало?

Comment: @LeonidKadenuk Потому что в массиве всего девять элементов с индексами от нуля до восьми.